# Finding value of F distribution without special calculator or table?

Tags: p-value, f-distribution

When performing a t-test, the calculation of p-values related to this are given as:

[image]

Is there a way to find $F(.)$ using a t-distribution table or a normal distribution table? (i.e. without a special calculator or $F$ distribution table)